# AutoMapper Take Properties from Child

Tags: c#, automapper

My model is similar to the following:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class SourceContainer
{
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    public string ExtraData { get; set; }
}

public class SourceViewModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string ExtraData { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, SourceViewModel>();
```

When I want to map from Source to SourceViewModel, everything is fine and I just don't have `ExtraData` populated. But I also want to map from a `SourceContainer` to `SourceViewModel`, preferably without specifying the mapping for each property.

Is it possible to tell AutoMapper to import properties from a child property, Source, when doing the mapping? Something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceContainer, SourceViewModel>()
    .UseMappingForProperty(x => x.Source);
```

Otherwise I can tell AutoMapper about each property on `SourceViewModel` separately and get it from the child Source, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `.ConstructUsing` to initialize the resulting `SourceViewModel` with the results of mapping the inner `Source` property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceContainer, SourceViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(container => Mapper.Map<SourceViewModel>(container.Source));
```

`ExtraData` will be mapped conventially after the `SourceViewModel` is constructed.